# Accessing existing Google Sheet with Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-drive-api

There's an existing google sheet that I need to read from with a Python script.  Is there any way I can enable the Google Sheets or Drive API for an existing spreadsheet (so I can download the necessary credentials for a Python app)?

All the online guides tell you how to do this for a New Project (like [this one](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/02/an-easy-way-to-read-and-write-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-python.html) or [this one](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python)) but not an existing sheet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Google Developers quickstart, you can see the constants

```py
# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms'
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Class Data!A2:E'
```

If you look at your sheet URL, you'll see it has a separate ID. You can replace the spreadsheet ID in the code with your own URL, and change the range you're querying depending on your specific application.